# Convert Access Query To sql With last of date and max

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to convert this query.
To use it in sql.
I dont know how to use las and max with group with having

```
SELECT     main.id, 
           main.rep1, 
           main.NAME, 
           main.family, 
           main.ostan, 
           main.city, 
           main.telhome, 
           Max(report.nextc) AS maxofnextc, 
           main.status, 
           Last(report.date)    AS lastofdate, 
           Last(report.connect) AS lastofconnect, 
           main.hospital, 
           main.[Bimeh-Not], 
           main.tamin, 
           main.khadamat, 
           main.niroo, 
           main.emdad, 
           main.takmili, 
           main.sayer, 
           main.darmangar 
FROM       main 
INNER JOIN report 
ON         main.id = report.id 
GROUP BY   main.id, 
           main.rep1, 
           main.NAME, 
           main.family, 
           main.ostan, 
           main.city, 
           main.telhome, 
           main.status, 
           main.hospital, 
           main.[Bimeh-Not], 
           main.tamin, 
           main.khadamat, 
           main.niroo, 
           main.emdad, 
           main.takmili, 
           main.sayer, 
           main.darmangar 
HAVING     ((( main.rep1) LIKE "BEN") 
           AND (( Max(report.nextc))<=[تاريخ روز جاري را وارد نماييد]) 
           AND (  main.status)<>4 
           AND (  main.status)<>1 
           AND (  main.status)<>5))
ORDER BY   max(report.nextc) DESC , 
           main.status, 
           last(report.connect);
```

Comment: I want to move it to crm 2013 reports.

Comment: SQL is a generic language.  What database are you moving it to?  Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: I mentioned in the comment crm 2013 it means sql 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL table represent *unordered* sets, so there is no `LAST()` without some mention of ordering.  Of course, that doesn't really help you, because MS Access does have some notion of order.

Let me guess that the ordering is really based on `date`, so you want some most recent fields.  If so, something like the following should solve your problem:

```
SELECT m.*, r.nextc AS maxofnextc, r.date AS lastofdate, 
       r.connect AS lastofconnect 
FROM main m JOIN
     (SELECT r.*, row_number() over (partition by r.id order by r.date desc) as seqnum
      FROM report r
     ) r
     ON m.id = r.id AND seqnum = 1
WHERE m.rep1 LIKE 'BEN' AND
      m.status not in (1, 4, 5)
      r.nextc <='تاريخ روز جاري را وارد نماييد'
ORDER BY r.nextc DESC , m.status, r.connect;
```